# How to use Event-Observer model send order No. to external PHP file & include that external PHP file in Magento's Observer.php?

Tags: php, mysql, magento, include, observer-pattern

I am using Magento's **Event-Observer model** at an event **sales_order_place_after** to get Order id (increment id) from Magento i.e. at the **event as soon as customer press PLACE ORDER**. So for that I created **config.xml** & **Observer.php** .

/xampp/htdocs/localhost/magento/app/code/local/Sample/Event/etc/config.xml

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Sample_Event>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Sample_Event>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <events>
            <sales_order_place_after>
                <observers>
                    <Sample_Event_Model_Observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Sample_Event_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>Mytestmethod</method>
                    </Sample_Event_Model_Observer>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

/xampp/htdocs/localhost/magento/app/code/local/Sample/Event/Model/Observer.php
**Observer.php**

```
<?php

 include("connection/Final/Function1.php");


class Sample_Event_Model_Observer 
{
    public function Mytestmethod($observer) 
   {
      $event = $observer->getEvent();       
    $eventmsg = "Current Event Triggered : <I>" . $event->getName() . "</I>";
      echo Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addSuccess($eventmsg);

    $Id = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getId();   
    $incrementid = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getIncrementId();

    $ordermsg1 = "Current order Id : <I>" . $Id . "</I>";
        echo Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addSuccess($ordermsg1);
    $ordermsg2 = "Current increment Id : <I>" . $incrementid . "</I>";
        echo Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addSuccess($ordermsg2);

       /* $cURL = curl_init();   //this isn't work for me
        curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/magento/connection/Final/Function1.php?order_id=<?php echo $incrementid ?>"); 
        curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
        curl_exec($cURL); 
        curl_close($cURL); 
       */ 

        $p = new testDatabase();      //this isn't work for me
        $p -> setId($incrementid);
        $p -> dbConnect();  
    }
}
```

?>

In Observer.php, I get order No.(increment id) as soon as customer places order. Now my aim is to pass that order No. to external php file Function1.php which has function that are dependent on Order No.(increment id).
**Function1.php**

```
<?php 

    //$orderID = $_GET['incrementid']; 
    //echo $orderID;    
class testDatabase 
{    
    public function setId($getId) //get Order Id i.e. Increment id from Observer.php which is not working for me
    {
        $incrementid=$getId;
        echo **$incrementid**;
    }   
    public function dbConnect()   //connect to magento database
    {   
      $db_name = "magento";
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "magento", "password");

        If (!$con)
        {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        $seldb = mysql_select_db($db_name, $con);
        If ($seldb) 
        {
            echo "Database Found ";
        }
        else 
        {
            echo "Database NOT Found ";
        } 
     }

    public function dbInsert()  //insert into magento's newly created custom table based on **increment id**.
      {
       echo "<br />";
      $query = "INSERT INTO mysql_outbound(po_number , created_at , buyer_customer_firstname , buyer_customer_lastname , buyer_customer_email , 
shipping_description , ship_to_firstname, ship_to_lastname, ship_to_company, ship_to_street, ship_to_city, ship_to_region, 
ship_to_country_id, ship_to_postcode, ship_to_telephone, bill_to_firstname, bill_to_lastname, bill_to_company, bill_to_street, bill_to_city, 
bill_to_region, bill_to_country_id, bill_to_postcode, bill_to_telephone, dealer_group_code, customer_group_code, dealer_firstname, 
dealer_lastname, customer_firstname, customer_lastname, increment_id, order_primary) 
SELECT sfop.`po_number`,sfo.`created_at`,sfo.`customer_firstname` , sfo.`customer_lastname` , sfo.`customer_email` , sfo.`shipping_description` , 
sfoa. firstname, sfoa. lastname, sfoa. company, sfoa. street, sfoa. city, sfoa. region, sfoa.country_id, sfoa. postcode, sfoa. telephone, sfoa1. firstname,
sfoa1. lastname, sfoa1. company, sfoa1. street, sfoa1. city, sfoa1. region, sfoa1.country_id, sfoa1. postcode, sfoa1. telephone, cg. customer_group_code,
cg1. customer_group_code, cev. value, cev1. value, cev2. value, cev3. value, sfo.`increment_id`, 
(select mo.order_primary from mysql_outbound mo where mo.increment_id = sfo.increment_id)
FROM `sales_flat_order_payment` sfop, `sales_flat_order` sfo, `sales_flat_order_address` sfoa,`sales_flat_order_address` sfoa1,`customer_entity` ce,`customer_entity` ce1,
`customer_group`  cg,`customer_group`  cg1,`customer_entity_varchar` cev, `customer_entity_varchar` cev1,`customer_entity_varchar` cev2,
`customer_entity_varchar` cev3
WHERE sfo.`entity_id` = sfop.`parent_id` 
    AND sfo.`shipping_address_id` = sfoa.`entity_id`
    AND sfo.`billing_address_id` = sfoa1.`entity_id`
    AND sfo. ge_dealer_id =  ce. entity_id
    AND ce. group_id = cg. customer_group_id
    AND sfo. ge_customer_id = ce1. entity_id
    AND ce1. group_id = cg1. customer_group_id
    AND sfo. ge_dealer_id = cev.entity_id
    AND cev. attribute_id = 5
    AND sfo. ge_dealer_id = cev1.entity_id
    AND cev1. attribute_id = 7
    AND sfo. ge_customer_id = cev2.entity_id
    AND cev2. attribute_id = 5
    AND sfo. ge_customer_id = cev3.entity_id
    AND cev3. attribute_id = 7
    AND sfo.`increment_id` = **$incrementid**";  //will need to pass increment id here

            $result = mysql_query($query);
     }

    public function dbFetch()       //fetch data from magento
    {
        global $str; 
        echo "<br />";
            $a = mysql_insert_id();
        echo $a;
        echo "<br />";    
            $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mysql_outbound where order_primary = $a");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
        {   
            $str = "'". $row["po_number"] . "',". "'" . $row[created_at] . "'," . "'" . $row["buyer_customer_firstname"] . "',". "'" . $row["buyer_customer_lastname"] . "'," . "'" . $row["buyer_customer_email"] . "'," . "'" . $row["shipping_description"]. "'," . "'" . $row["ship_to_firstname"] . "'," . "'" . $row["ship_to_lastname"] ."'," . "'" . $row["ship_to_company"] . "'," . "'" . $row["ship_to_street"] ."'," ."'" . $row["ship_to_city"] . "'," ."'" . $row["ship_to_region"] . "'," ."'" . $row["ship_to_country_id"] ."'," ."'" . $row["ship_to_postcode"]."'," ."'" . $row["ship_to_telephone"] . "'," ."'" . $row["bill_to_firstname"] . "'," ."'" . $row["bill_to_lastname"] ."'," ."'" . $row["bill_to_company"]."'," ."'" . $row["bill_to_street"] . "'," ."'" . $row["bill_to_city"] ."'," ."'" . $row["bill_to_region"] . "'," ."'" . $row["bill_to_country_id"] ."'," ."'" . $row["bill_to_postcode"] . "'," ."'" . $row["bill_to_telephone"] . "'," ."'" . $row["dealer_group_code"] ."'," ."'" . $row["customer_group_code"]."'," ."'" . $row["dealer_firstname"] . "'," ."'" . $row["dealer_lastname"] ."'," ."'" . $row["customer_firstname"] . "'," ."'" . $row["customer_lastname"] ."'," ."'" . $row["increment_id"] . "'," . $row["order_primary"];
            } 
    }

     public function dbDisconnect()     //close mysql connection
     {   
        echo "<br />";
          If($this->con)   
          {   
               If(mysql_close())   
               {   
                $this->con = false;   
                return true;
               }   
               else  
               {   
                return false;   
               }   
           }
        }
```

}

Now I want to include this file Function1.php in Observer.php so that as soon as customer press PLACE ORDER tab Function1.php file will get Order No. & it will execute queries in it. I just wanted to insert data into custom table which is needed to send to external system i.e. Oracle. As we don't want to touch Magento core tables so created custom table for the same..

Now my questions are:

1. How to pass Order No. from Observer.php to Function1.php?
2. How to include Function1.php in Observer.php so that once customer places order this file will get executed as It will get Order No. to do the job?

Please provide me your help or sample code for the same...

I tried to connect with creating object & accessing functions but failed to do that.

Also tried to use cURL but that also didn't work for me...

Waiting for responses & suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would start by making your external class part of a Magento module. Then, you can create your own resource/helpers to power the connection to the other database.

In your module's `config.xml`

```
 <mymodule_setup>
    <connection>
    <host>< ![CDATA[hostname]]></host>
    <username>< ![CDATA[username]]></username>
    <password>< ![CDATA[password]]></password>
    <dbname>< ![CDATA[dbname]]></dbname>
    <model>mysql4</model>
    <initstatements>SET NAMES utf8</initstatements>
    <type>pdo_mysql</type>
    <active>1</active>
    </connection>
</mymodule_setup>
<mymodule_write>
    <connection>
    <use>mymodule_setup</use>
    </connection>
</wp_write>
<mymodule_read>
    <connection>
    <use>mymodule_setup</use>
    </connection>
</mymodule_read>
```

Then you can access this DB anywhere from Magento with

```
$read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('mymodule_read');
$write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('mymodule_write');
```

It will give you an instance of [Zend DB](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.html&ei=Mr1kT4z6DIa28QPYhNiiCA&usg=AFQjCNHMbkHd66H4Ng1TKYoqxEpcOzUbzQ&sig2=4ilcUHIMJ19RIfB_cFaevA) that you can do whatever you want with. This will avoid having to mess about passing data from Magento to elsewhere, including external classes etc.

Comment: Hi Sonassi,Looking at my code & the scenario, how should I pass order No. to Function1.php & include Function1.php in Observer.php. Plz guide me or provide me sample code for the same...

Comment: I've given you all the code you need, this is a Q&A site for guidance, not a place for someone to write an entire module for you :(